# Is there a reason why identity server 4 returns a 404 error when logging out in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, iis-8, windows-server-2012

i'm currently experiencing an issue in production with my implementation of identity server 4.

When i perform a login i get redirected to the identity server and i can authenticate without any issues.

My problem comes in when i try and log out. I get redirected to the identityserver on the "connect/endsession" endpoint and a 404 is returned.

I even tried with all browsers, all the same issue.
production : MS server 2012, iis 8 and .net core 2.1

here are a few code examples :

In my client startup :

```
services.AddAuthentication(option => {
            option.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            option.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";


        }).AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"]; // identity.example.com
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"]; //example.mvc
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:ClientSecret"] //!@examplepassword@! ;

        });
```

in the account controller i have this logout method

```
 public async Task Logout()
    {

        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");


    }
```

In the identity server

My client store implementation pulls a client object from a json file and maps it correctly, i know that bit works.

```
{
  "Enable": true,
  "ClientId": "example.mvc",
  "ClientName": "example enterprise ",
  "RedirectUris": [ "http://www.example.com/signin-oidc" ],
  "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "http://www.example.com/signout-callback-oidc" ],
  "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true,
  "RequireConsent": false,
  "ClientSecret": "!@examplepassword@!",
  "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "email" ],
  "GrantType": "implicitandclientcredentials"
}
```

When clicking on logout i expect to be logged out permanently. But for some reason i get a 404 error.

Not sure if i must add a controller that has a [Route("/signout-callback-oidc")], but for some reason i just cant get the logout to work in production.

funny enough it works locally on my pc i try and debug it.

Comment: Probably https redirect. You can try change the url to https.

Comment: Thank's, i've tried that. It doesnt work

Comment: although the identityserver is running under https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out to be a max url length limitation in iis that, when hit, returned a 404. I've modified the .AddOpenIdConnect method in the startup.cs file and added in one line.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"];
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:ClientSecret"];
            options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.FormPost; // adding this line fixed my problem. and i can now logout permanently. 

        });
```

Comment: I'm using IIS, and length limitation was my problem aswell. I fixed it by elevating the query length in web.config by adding:  <requestLimits maxQueryString="8192" /> under <configuration><system.webServer><security><requestFiltering>. Default value is 2048.

Comment: Is there any side effects or security considerations using POST instead of GET for endSession endpoint?

Comment: If you use GET and you have IIS logs turned on it will appear in the logs. Not with POST.